How can I using common routes for multi-projects
I am using NuxtJs 3 and I have 3 folders containing 3 different nuxtjs projects in which the "packages" folder contains 2 subfolders "cms" and "monitor". When I run the project "package", I want my home page to be the entire "monitor" folder with the path as "/monitor" and when I access the path: "/cms" then the entire project's I will be folder "cms". The path is as follows: "
packages/
├── cms/
│ └── nuxt.config.ts
├── monitoring/
│ └── nuxt.config.ts
└── nuxt.config.ts"
I want when I run the "packages" project, I can access the routers of the child projects
